Incorporate Additional Data Into Allure Report
I'd like to incorporate some additional data into my allure reports - video and graphics primarily.
I'm using flank to run tests against firebase test lab. I've got the test results being pulled down and incorporated into my allure report, including screenshots taken during the test runs. However, firebase records a video for the whole run, and for individual tests, if they're long enough (I don't have any that are). The whole run shows up as a "video.mp4" file in the root of the folder pulled back from the cloud bucket along with the allure results.  I'd like to be able to incorporate this video into the allure results.
I've also started using the alpha compose screenshot testing for Android.  This includes before/after images, and an analysis in the junit test results.  I have the junit test results being incorporated in my allure report, but would like to be able to include the before/after graphics as well.
I'm using allure-kotlin, and gradle kotlinscript to drive all this.  Any assistance would be appreciated.
